# StackOverflowExeption converting Dictionary<T, V> to List<KeyValuePair<T, V>>

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I'm not the best at C# and I got a stack overflow exeption in this code:

```
private Dictionary<T, V> collection;
internal List<KeyValuePair<T, V>> ToList()
{
    return collection.ToList(); //the VS debugger breaked here
}
```

Here is the full class: http://pastebin.com/ji0Vrm0X
Hope someone can find the stack overflow exeption.

heres some more information :$

```
  internal QueuedDictionary<int, RoomUser> UserList
        {
            get
            {
                return userlist;
            }
        }

    internal List<RoomUser> GetRoomUsers()
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<int, RoomUser>> users = UserList.ToAList();

        List<RoomUser> returnList = new List<RoomUser>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, RoomUser> pair in users)
        {
            if (!pair.Value.IsBot)
                returnList.Add(pair.Value);
        }

        return returnList;
    }
```

Comment: Please post all relevant code here. How do we see your code if Pastebin goes down?

Comment: Look at the call stack, are you seeing a long string of calls to your `ToList()` method?

Comment: there is nothing in the callstack :(. 
I get this exeption 1 time in 2 days running :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly create new `KeyValuePair<T,V>` elements from the dictionary, then make a list of it:

```
internal List<KeyValuePair<T, V>> ToList()
{
    return collection.Select(kvp => new KeyValuePair<T,V>(kvp.Key, kvp.Value).ToList(); 
}
```

Should perform the action you want.

**Edit** I would've expected your code to work as well. Could be that a Dictionary's `.ToList()` method does something similar to `.Select(x => x.Value)` as opposed to returning a `List<KeyValuePair<X,Y>>`.
But that'd just be my guess.

Comment: Thanks hope that your code dont give a stack overflow exeption anymore thanks :)